# How to convert array to object array with custom key in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am learning typescript. It might be a silly question, but I am not able to find the answer online. I would like to convert an array to an object array (values are from the array). For example:

Input:

```
const array = ["Tom", "Jack", "Rose"]
```

Expected ouput:

```
[
  {
    name: "Tom",
    initial: "t",
    year: "2021"
  },
  {
    name: "Jack",
    initial: "j",
    year: "2021"
  },
  {
    name: "Rose",
    initial: "r",
    year: "2021"
  },
]
```

What is the best way to achieve this in typescript?

Thanks!

Comment: Little confused from your question, are you asking how to create the object from the array or how to define that name property can only be from array [A,B,C]

Comment: I would say latter, but basically, I am asking what the best way to get the expected output from example input. I updated a bit, and hope it is less confusion now.

Comment: Checkout the map function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This maybe the easiest way:

```js
const array = ["Tom", "Jack", "C"]

const newObj = [];

array.forEach(eachArrayElement => {
  const x = {
    name: eachArrayElement,
    initial: eachArrayElement[0].toLowerCase(),
    year: (new Date().getFullYear()).toString()
  };
  newObj.push(x);
})

console.log('New Obj ==>', newObj);
```

Comment: Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). It is more appropriate for the goal (transform one array into another.)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe even easier:

```js
const array = ['Tom', 'Jack', 'Rose'];

const arrayOfObjects = array.map(element => {
  return {
    name: element,
    initial: element.charAt(0),
    year: new Date().getFullYear().toString(),
  };
});

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

Comment: `map` is the way to go. Please add `element.charAt(0).toLowerCase()` for the sake of completeness